# How to systematically update a C++ dependency that I once manually installed from binary

Tags: c++

Scenario:

I wish to use [Google OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/cpp) with it C++ version as a dependency in my C++ project. I choose to install it from binary. I download the binary file and use the provided `Makefile` to install it.

Question:

In the future, when a new version of OR-Tools is released, how do I update the dependency in my local project?

If I were using Python, JavaScript or Ruby, I'd use `pip`, `npm/yarn` or `gem` (i.e. package managers) to update dependencies. But since C++ doesn't really have one, how do I **systematically** update C++ dependencies that I installed from binary?

Comment: _"But since C++ doesn't really have one, how do I systematically approach this task?"_ C++ has many package managers. [Conan](https://conan.io/) is probably the most used cross platform dependency/package manager.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasSablik. Since OR-Tools is not listed on ConanCenter, does it mean I need to create and host my own Canon server?

Comment: You can create your own repository on their server.

Comment: Worth mentioning [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is also one of the well-maintained and fast-evolving package manager for c++

Comment: @Skyler you can contribute recipes to ConanCenter with a pull request to: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index (need to ask for EAP access first), or you can host your own private packages for free running a ArtifactoryCE (https://conan.io/downloads.html) in your server.

Comment: @nop666 vcpkg is Windows only. pip, npm/yarn and gem are cross platform. Of course it can be mentioned in the list of 20 package managers for C++ next to Buckaro, Hunter, Meson, Spack, ... but I think Conan has a special position in this list.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik It is not Windows only. I use it on Linux (alongside conan by the way). About the special position, it's your opinion, no pb!

Comment: @nop666 I didn't know it. Perhaps I should try it out.

Comment: @drodri I'm a little confused about the documentation of contributing recipes to ConanCenter. (1) What is a "recipe"? (2) Can I contribute a new recipe with a 3rd-party dependency that I did not create (such as Google's OR-Tools)?

Comment: @Skyler  A recipe is a ``conanfile.py`` python script that defines the steps to build and package from source, and also how to consume the package. Have a look to: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html. Yes, you can contribute recipes to 3rd-parties that you didn't create, that is very normal in ConanCenter, packages are created and maintained by community, not necessarily authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I systematically update C++ dependencies that I installed from binary?

Write a script that fetches and installs the dependencies however you wish or setup one of the many package managers or build systems with package support that C++ has.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do when my project relies on 3rd party code is create a Git repository for your project (if you don't already have one) and add the third party code as a Git submodule. That way, you can easily just pull the latest changes that were committed to the repository of the third party code.

You can optimize your workflow even more by adding this third party project to your project and change your project's config to consider the third party project to be a dependency. That way, it will compile the dependency every time a change was made to it.